# Dynamically set the "selected" attribute using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({   
    type: "POST",
    url: "localhost/api.php",
    data: {id:user_id},
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {

        var obj = $.parseJSON(data); 
        if (obj.msg == "1")
        {
            $.each(obj.userList, function(i,value) {
                var jArray = <?php echo json_encode($groupData ); ?>;
                list = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < jArray.length; i++) {
                    list.push('<option id=' + jArray[i].Group_Id + ' value=' + jArray[i].Group_Name + '>' + jArray[i].Group_Name + '</option>');
                }
                var html ="<tr>"+
                        "<td>"+value['id']+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+value['groupID']+"</td>"+ 
                        "<td><select name='Group[]''>"+list+ "</select></td>";
                $('table#List tbody').append(html);

            });
        }
    },
    alert('Error');
});
```

I'm dynamically constructing the html based on the ajax response. 
In the code snippet >

```
 var jArray = <?php echo json_encode($groupData ); ?>;
 list = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < jArray.length; i++) {
      list.push('<option id=' + jArray[i].Group_Id + ' value=' + jArray[i].Group_Name + '>' + jArray[i].Group_Name + '</option>');
 }
```

`$groupData` is a PHP array. So I'm converting it into a Javascript array and using this `jArray` to generate the "option" and push the resulting list array. I'm appending this `list` array into the html and this much is working perfectly. Now there are 6 groups and one of them is already set for a particular user in the database. So currently none of the "option" has selected attribute. I'm having trouble in comparing `jArray[i].Group_Id` with `value['groupID']`. What I want to achieve is I want to compare `jArray[i].Group_Id` with `value['groupID']` and if they are equal then set a selected attribute to that particular . How do I write an `if` statement for the comparison inside the "option" ?

Comment: what's preventing you from comparing the two values? One thing I see is that you don't decode your json to an actual array in the js code.

Comment: actually I'm not able to figure out how to write the if statement inside the <option> correctly.

Comment: oh, you are looking for a ternary operator "...id="+ ( a == b ? "yes" : "no" ) + "... rest of string"

Comment: exactly. I just want to achieve something like <option if(jArray[i].Group_Id = value['groupID']) > and if they are equal then add a "selected" attribute to the option with reference to my code as I'm creating a string of options

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's some example code showing this working:

```js
const jArray = [{Group_Id: 1, Group_Name: 'One'}, {Group_Id: 2, Group_Name: 'Two'}];
const userList = [{id: 'user1', groupID: 2}, {id: 'user2', groupID: 2}, {id: 'user3', groupID: 1}];
$.each(userList, function(x,value) {
  list = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < jArray.length; i++) {
    list.push('<option id=' + jArray[i].Group_Id + ' value=' + jArray[i].Group_Name + (jArray[i].Group_Id == value.groupID ? ' selected ' : '') + '>' + jArray[i].Group_Name + '</option>');
  }
  var html ="<tr>"+
      "<td>"+value.id+"</td>"+
      "<td>"+value.groupID+"</td>"+ 
      "<td><select name='Group[]''>"+list+ "</select></td>";
  $('table#List tbody').append(html);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="List">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

The important piece missing from your code being:

```
(jArray[i].Group_Id == value.groupID ? ' selected ' : '')
```

Comment: thank you so much. this is exactly what I wanted to achieve.